# How to send Mime type attachment to REST API through c#

Tags: c#, rest, curl

I have to send MIME type attachment to REST API and we are getting the issue in it. I have asked to API support they suggest the solution by `curl` request please find the `curl` request bellow

```
curl -ki -X POST -v -F auth_info='{"login":"02781","password":"joiuuV2r","domain":"68.146.98.31", "session_id":null}' -F params='{"i_menu":1573,"transition_info":{"event":"4","action":"Transfer","target_i_menu":1573,"destination":"200","play_prompt":"Y","prompt":"ZZZ.mp3"}}' -F upload_file="@/tmp/ringtone.mp3;type=audio/mpeg" https://posturl
```

I am not getting this code but i have tried to send MIME type attachment like

```
     string fileName = file.FileName;// "menu.au";
     byte[] byteFiles = new byte[file.ContentLength];
     file.InputStream.Read(byteFiles, 0, file.ContentLength);
     using (HttpContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteFiles, 0, byteFiles.Length))
          {
               string mimeType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);

                                    //specifying MIME Type
               fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(mimeType);

               content.Add(fileContent, "upload_file", fileName);
               var result = client.PostAsync(postUrl, content).Result;
          }
```

this request getting the response 200 success, but file is not uploading.
Please suggest me any solution. Thank you.

Comment: has your query exceeded the max length parameter set by the API owner?

Comment: @markthewizard1234 no if it exceeds then API will response with error.